# close all open dynamic dialogs on logout

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using primeng dynamic dialog to show some data in a component.However if the dialog is opened & the session times out, the app logs out but the dialog remains open. I want to close the dialog since the app has logged out. I tried calling DynamicDialogRef close() method but that's not working. How can I do this?

This is what I'm calling inside the sign out method -

```
 constructor private dialogRef: DynamicDialogRef) { }

 signOut()
        {
        this.dialogRef.close();
        this.dialogRef.destroy();
  }
```

This is how I'm calling the dialog-
Template

```
   <button (click)="showDialog()"></button>
```

The method called:

```
showDialog() {
   
    const ref = this.dialogService.open(DetailsDialogComponent, {

      data: {
        value: 'TEST,
      },
      header: 'Details Panel",
      width: '70%',
      dismissableMask: true
    });

    
      }
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML template that you are using to show the primeng dialog?

Comment: can u create in https://stackblitz.com/ for the issue ?

Comment: @AngelaAmarapala I've added more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So unlike mat dialog, primeng doesn't provide a method to close all dialogs at once, to achieve this I had to use the following -

```
 this.dialogService.dialogComponentRefMap.forEach(dialog => {
      dialog.destroy();
    });
```

Comment: I implemented it like this 
=>
 private _destroyOpenDialogs(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.dialogService.dialogComponentRefMap.forEach((dialog) =>
          dialog.destroy()
        );
      }
    });
  }

Comment: For some reason this did not work for me and many other solutions.
I found pretty simple solution.
I have called the dialogref.close() in every components onDestroy life cycle wherever it was opened.So, if the component gets destroyed the dialogref does too.

Answer (score 0):

The `primeng` dialog has a two-way binding `[(visible)]` property that allows you to set a boolean value to it. By default, the value is `false`. So the same `false` flag can be used to close all your active dialogs when you perform some action (in your case its logout).

In your HTML template, do the following:

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="openDialog1">
...
</p-dialog>
<p-dialog [(visible)]="openDialog2">
...
</p-dialog>
```

And in your ts file,

```
signOut() {
    this.openDialog1 = false;
    this.openDialog2 = false; // set for all the dialogs that you want to close
}
```

***Updated:***

If you aren't using `p-dialog`, try adding `[DialogService]` to the `providers` section of your component as follows,

```
providers: [DialogService]
```

**Closing a dynamic dialog with data:**

```
signOut() {
   this.dialogRef.close(data); // pass your data 
}
```

Then, use the `onClose` event to catch it. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not using p-dialog since I want to show some dynamic content in my dialog. Hence I'm using the dialog service to open my component.

Comment: @piqueblinders do you have `[DialogService]` added to your component's `providers` section? Pls refer to the updated answer for more

Comment: Yes I've added it to my component's provider section.

Comment: Also when you pass data to the dialog, you must pass data while closing the dialog too. It seems that your close event is empty

Comment: I don't need the data to be passed when the close event is initiated, hence I wasn't passing it. Also you're probably referring to initiating the close event from the dynamic dialog, I want to close it from another component.

Answer (score 0):

Create own service for injection;

```
import { DynamicDialogRef, DialogService } from 'primeng/dynamicdialog';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DialogDynamicService {
  ref: DynamicDialogRef;
  constructor(private service: DialogService) {
  }

  open(ref, data){
     this.ref =  this.service.open(ref, {})
  }

  destroy(){
   if(this.ref){
      this.ref.destroy();
   }
  }
}
```

call your Component in service,

```
constructor(private dialogService: DialogDynamicService){}
    
  getDialog(){
        this.dialogService.open(DialogComponent,{});
    }
```

Session logout

```
constructor(public dialogService: DialogDynamicService) {}
signOut(){
 this.dialogService.destroy();
}
```

Don't forget to put `DialogService` in `app Module` or `root Module`

Hope this one will solve your issue.
if not comment down.! thankyou